# Erro na função Find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Estou com uma função para listar todos os meus registros do banco, mas ela não está retornando todos os registros, está dando erro,[image: teste da rota][image: rota para listar todos os usuários] `async all(req, res){ //Função para listamento de todos os usuários

await Model.find()

```
    .then(response =>{

        if(response)

            return res.status(200).json(response);
    })    
    .catch(error =>{
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    });

}`
```

estou usando JavaScript / Node.js e de banco estou utilizando o MongoDb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema pode estar no `.find()`, note que essa função espera um parâmetro (obrigatório) chamado `filter`. A documentação sugere que você utilize um objeto vazio `{}` caso não queira aplicar filtros ([veja](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)).

```js
await Model.find({}).then((response) => { });
```